# ServletContextListener.contextInitialized doesnt get called when context is initialised

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am creating a war file (progressReporter.war) and i am deploying it on Jetty7.2.2.v20101205. I have a sysout on contextInitialized method which i should see when jetty starts up. I am starting jetty using
java -jar start.jar

Java version is 1.6

Same thing when i am running on tomcat, its running absolutely fine. For jetty i have included

- jetty-client-7.2.2.v20101205.jar
- jetty-continuation-7.2.2.v20101205.jar
- jetty-http-7.2.2.v20101205.jar
- jetty-io-7.2.2.v20101205.jar
- jetty-servlets-7.2.2.v20101205.jar
- jetty-util-7.2.2.v20101205.jar

Following is what i have in

```
@Override  
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {  
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"spring-http-config.xml", "test-spring-http-config.xml", "spring-ibatis.xml" });  
    System.out.println("setting attribute now ............... " + servletContextEvent.getServletContext());  
}
```

Following is what i have in web.xml

```
<listener>  
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener  
    </listener-class>  
    <listener-class>com.client.BatchProgressorContextListener  
   </listener-class>  
</listener>
```

Can you please help me what's going wrong here?

Following is the output when i start jetty:

```
C:\bkup\trialLearning\jetty>java -jar start.jar
2011-01-01 20:04:10.510:INFO::jetty-7.2.2.v20101205
2011-01-01 20:04:10.525:INFO::Deployment monitor C:\bkup\trialLearning\jetty\web
apps at interval 1
2011-01-01 20:04:10.525:INFO::Deployable added: C:\bkup\trialLearning\jetty\weba
pps\progressReporter.war
2011-01-01 20:04:10.666:INFO::Copying WEB-INF/lib jar:file:/C:/bkup/trialLearnin
g/jetty/webapps/progressReporter.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ to C:\Documents and Settings\
i143628\Local Settings\Temp\jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-progressReporter.war-_progressRep
orter-any-\webinf\WEB-INF\lib
2011-01-01 20:04:12.213:INFO:progressReporter:Initializing Spring root WebApplic
ationContext
0    [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Root WebAppli
cationContext: initialization started
31   [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationConte
xt  - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Jan 01 20:04:12 I
ST 2011]; root of context hierarchy
93   [main] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader
 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-http-config.xml
]
203  [main] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader
 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [test-spring-http-confi
g.xml]
218  [main] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader
 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-ibatis.xml]
390  [main] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderCo
nfigurer  - Loading properties file from class path resource [qpr-config.propert
ies]
406  [main] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanF
actory  - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.supp
ort.DefaultListableBeanFactory@e66f56: defining beans [org.springframework.conte
xt.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.conte
xt.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.a
nnotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annota
tion.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,batchProgressUpdater,batchProgressMetrics
,progressReporterResultsQueue,cbbEventProcessorThread,timerEventProcessorThread,
eventThreadManager,eventListener,metricsAggregator,southbeachDummyClient,cbbPric
er,dummyCbb,processorThread,counterGenerater,imntInfoDao,imntStatsInfoDao,org.sp
ringframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,dataSource,sq
lMapClient]; root of factory hierarchy
593  [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Root WebAppli
cationContext: initialization completed in 593 ms
2011-01-01 20:04:12.947:INFO::Deployment monitor C:\bkup\trialLearning\jetty\con
texts at interval 1
2011-01-01 20:04:12.947:INFO::Deployable added: C:\bkup\trialLearning\jetty\cont
exts\test.xml
2011-01-01 20:04:12.978:INFO::Extract jar:file:/C:/bkup/trialLearning/jetty/weba
pps/test.war!/ to C:\Documents and Settings\i143628\Local Settings\Temp\jetty-0.
0.0.0-8080-test.war-_-any-\webapp
2011-01-01 20:04:13.572:INFO:org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.TransparentProxy:Transpa
rentProxy @ /javadoc to http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs
2011-01-01 20:04:13.572:INFO::Deployable added: C:\bkup\trialLearning\jetty\cont
exts\javadoc.xml
2011-01-01 20:04:13.588:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
2011-01-01 20:12:59.369:INFO::Graceful shutdown SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8
080
2011-01-01 20:12:59.447:INFO::Graceful shutdown o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/progressR
eporter,[file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/i143628/Local%20Settings/Temp/jetty
-0.0.0.0-8080-progressReporter.war-_progressReporter-any-/webinf/, jar:file:/C:/
bkup/trialLearning/jetty/webapps/progressReporter.war!/]},C:\bkup\trialLearning\
jetty\webapps\progressReporter.war
2011-01-01 20:12:59.447:INFO::Graceful shutdown o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/C:
/Documents%20and%20Settings/i143628/Local%20Settings/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-tes
t.war-_-any-/webapp/},C:\bkup\trialLearning\jetty/webapps/test.war
2011-01-01 20:12:59.478:INFO::Graceful shutdown o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler{/javado
c,file:/C:/bkup/trialLearning/jetty/javadoc}
2011-01-01 20:13:00.666:INFO:progressReporter:Closing Spring root WebApplication
Context
528453 [Thread-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicatio
nContext  - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Jan 01 20:04:1
2 IST 2011]; root of context hierarchy
528453 [Thread-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListabl
eBeanFactory  - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.suppo
rt.DefaultListableBeanFactory@e66f56: defining beans [org.springframework.contex
t.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.contex
t.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.an
notation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotat
ion.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,batchProgressUpdater,batchProgressMetrics,
progressReporterResultsQueue,cbbEventProcessorThread,timerEventProcessorThread,e
ventThreadManager,eventListener,metricsAggregator,southbeachDummyClient,cbbPrice
r,dummyCbb,processorThread,counterGenerater,imntInfoDao,imntStatsInfoDao,org.spr
ingframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,dataSource,sql
MapClient]; root of factory hierarchy
```

Can you please help me as to what i am doing wrong and what needs to be done to run on Jetty please? 
Please do let me know if you need any other details as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

- I see in log that context is going up:

> ```
> 3   [main] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader
> ```
>
> - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource
>   [spring-http-config.xml ] 203  [main]
>   INFO 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader
>    - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource
>   [test-spring-http-confi g.xml] 218 
>   [main] INFO 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader
>    - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource
>   [spring-ibatis.xml]

So your code is working.

- You write to console instead of writing to log file. Probably this is the reason why you don't see it. Try to use commons-logging to log your message.
- Why you have both ContextLoaderListener  and BatchProgressorContextListener  in web.xml? (I assume that BatchProgressorContextListener   is the one with code you gave in the beginning of post, right?)
  Probably you need only one context listener that will load your context and ContextLoaderListener  will be sufficient.
  Remove BatchProgressorContextListener from web.xml and add instead

> ```
>  <context-param>
>     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
>     <param-value> 
>        classpath:spring-http-config.xml
>        classpath:test-spring-http-config.xml
>        classpath:spring-ibatis.xml
>     </param-value>
> </context-param>
> ```

Comment: Thanks Tarlog. I had context-param. The thing was that in single listener tag i was defining both the listeners. Now i seperated out like this &lt;listener> &lt;listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener &lt;/listener-class> &lt;/listener> &lt;listener> &lt;listener-class>com.client.BatchProgressorContextListener &lt;/listener-class&lt;/listener> And now its working absolutely fine. Thanks Stackoverflow.